# Lua with VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I installed the extension sumneko for Lua in VS code. Unfortunately, nothing seems to work like for example Autocompletion and execution. What did I miss?

Comment: sumneko's lua language server is not a debugger, and when you say autocompletion does not work, what do you mean? how did you expect it to work and how did it not meet your expectations?